How to handle CORS configuration of API gateway and Socket in Springboot Microservices
I have a Springboot Microservice application. I have 4 microservices in my application.
API-gateway,
user-management,
idm-service,
engine-service.

I am using react as frontend here.
API-gateway contains CORS related configuration and I am using web-socket for my engine-service so it has web socket configuration.
I am facing issue while communicating with socket of engine-service.
When I am trying to initiate socket connection from react. First it will go to API-gateway so I have to add required CORS configuration in API-gateway.
API-gateway configuration:
cors-configurations:
  '[/**]':
    allowCredentials: true
    allowedOrigins:
      - "http://localhost:3000"
    allowedHeaders: "*"
    allowedMethods:
      - GET
      - POST
      - DELETE
      - PUT
      - OPTIONS
      - PATCH

I have to add allowCredentials: true to allow web socket connection and it is working fine.
engine-service socket configuration:
@Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint(registryEndpoint).setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000").withSockJS();
  }

Now again I have to add setAllowedOrigins in websocket configuration. so when request comes to engine-service, I am getting error like this
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:3000, http://localhost:3000', but only one is allowed.

Now I am unable to find solution for this. All the request must go via API-gateway so I have to add CORS configuration there else I will get CORS error in API-gateway. If I am adding setAllowedOrigins in API-gateway I am getting error in engine-service.
Can you please guide me on this error?
For websocket connection, Should I directly communicate with engine-service and not going via API-gateway?

Does this solve you query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54497267/spring-websocket-message-broker-adding-extra-access-control-allow-origin-header?

Yes, it is working fine. Thank you so much for the answer.
